# Converting Multiple 'old format' Joins in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, database-migration

I have the following structure of code in SQL Server. It uses multiple old format *= joins in the WHERE clause?

```
SELECT ....
FROM (select ...) L1,
     (select ...) L2,
     (select ...) SE,
     (select ...) EX,
     (select ...) SE,
     (select ...) Y1,
     (select ...) Y2,
     (select ...) Y3,
     (select ...) Y4,
     (select ...) Y5
WHERE SE.FV = EX.FV
    and SE.FV *= Y1.FV
    and SE.FV *= Y2.FV
    and SE.FV *= Y3.FV
    and SE.FV *= Y4.FV
    and SE.FV *= Y5.FV
    and SE.L1 *= L1.FV
    and SE.L2 *= L2.FV
GROUP BY L1.FV, L1.Descr, L2.FV, L2.Descr
ORDER BY L1.FV, L1.Descr, L2.FV, L2.Descr
```

In the real code, the selects are a mother of a mish-mash of dynamically generated sql. But in essence, the STRUCTURE is as I've shown above.

What should the STRUCTURE of the above template be, so that it uses proper LEFT OUTER JOIN syntax, without changing the logic of the query?

Would something like this work perhaps?

```
SELECT L1.FV, L1.Descr, L2.FV, L2.Descr, Y1.B, Y1.A, Y2.B, Y2.A, ...
FROM (select ...) SE
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (select ...) Y1 ON SE.FV = Y1.FV
        AND LEFT OUTER JOIN (select ...) Y2 ON SE.FV = Y2.FV
        AND LEFT OUTER JOIN (select ...) Y3 ON SE.FV = Y3.FV
        AND LEFT OUTER JOIN (select ...) Y4 ON SE.FV = Y4.FV
        AND LEFT OUTER JOIN (select ...) Y5 ON SE.FV = Y5.FV
        AND LEFT OUTER JOIN (select ...) L1 ON SE.L1 = L1.FV
        AND LEFT OUTER JOIN (select ...) L2 ON SE.L2 = L2.FV,
     (select ...) EX
WHERE SE.FV = EX.FV
GROUP BY L1.FV, L1.Descr, L2.FV, L2.Descr
ORDER BY L1.FV, L1.Descr, L2.FV, L2.Descr
```

Comment: Relevant: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: You already specified the GROUP BY columns, L1.FV, L1.Descr, L2.FV, L2.Descr. When you write the SELECT, any other column other than in GRROUP BY should be applied with a function. eg: MAX(Y1.B). Other than that, your query should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to separate the "mishmash of dynamically generated sql" from the STRUCTURE by using CTEs like this:

```
WITH 
    SE AS (select 1 AS X, 2 AS FV, 3 AS L1, 4 AS L2),
    EX AS (select 1 AS X, 2 AS FV),
    Y1 AS (select 1 AS X, 2 AS FV),
    Y2 AS (select 1 AS X, 2 AS FV),
    Y3 AS (select 1 AS X, 2 AS FV),
    Y4 AS (select 1 AS X, 2 AS FV),
    Y5 AS (select 1 AS X, 2 AS FV),
    L1 AS (select 1 AS X, 3 AS FV, 'y' AS Descr),
    L2 AS (select 1 AS X, 4 AS FV, 'z' AS Descr)
SELECT L1.FV, L1.Descr, L2.FV, L2.Descr
FROM 
     SE
     INNER JOIN EX ON EX.FV = SE.FV
     LEFT JOIN Y1 ON Y1.FV = SE.FV
     LEFT JOIN Y2 ON Y2.FV = SE.FV
     LEFT JOIN Y3 ON Y3.FV = SE.FV
     LEFT JOIN Y4 ON Y4.FV = SE.FV
     LEFT JOIN Y5 ON Y5.FV = SE.FV
     LEFT JOIN L1 ON L1.FV = SE.L1
     LEFT JOIN L2 ON L2.FV = SE.L2
GROUP BY L1.FV, L1.Descr, L2.FV, L2.Descr
ORDER BY L1.FV, L1.Descr, L2.FV, L2.Descr
```

Comment: The "AND" between different joins is incorrect syntax. Each JOIN is a separate clause from the rest; the "AND" you have provided will be syntactically attached to the end of the "ON" expression, yielding a syntax error.

Comment: And I do not understand why you wish to separate the `EX` table, putting it in a WHERE clause instead of an INNER JOIN clause. It will work but I don't see the necessity.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. It's quite a bit of code change (+200 lines), but your solution seems very elegant. So I'm giving it a go. I'm more of an analyst than a developer, so my SQL is very rusty!! :)

Answer (score 2):

I hope, your query can be brought to the below structure.

```
SELECT      L1.FV, 
            L1.Descr, 
            L2.FV, 
            L2.Descr,
            .. 
FROM                (select ...) L1
JOIN/LEFT JOIN      (select ...) L2 ON L2.Col = ....
JOIN/LEFT JOIN      (select ...) SE ON SE.Col = ....
JOIN/LEFT JOIN      (select ...) EX ON EX.Col = ....
JOIN/LEFT JOIN      (select ...) SE ON SE.Col = ....
JOIN/LEFT JOIN      (select ...) Y1 ON Y1.Col = ....
JOIN/LEFT JOIN      (select ...) Y2 ON Y2.Col = ....
JOIN/LEFT JOIN      (select ...) Y3 ON Y3.Col = ....
JOIN/LEFT JOIN      (select ...) Y4 ON Y4.Col = ....
JOIN/LEFT JOIN      (select ...) Y5 ON Y5.Col = ....
GROUP BY L1.FV, L1.Descr, L2.FV, L2.Descr
ORDER BY L1.FV, L1.Descr, L2.FV, L2.Descr;
```